# Web 8.5 GUI Extension: Need to execute either Save/ Localize/ Unlocalize command which triggers the GUI extension

Tags: web8.5, cme, gui-extensions

I need to implement some logic before saving/localizing/unlocalizing a Component. The logic would be the same so I use a GUI extension where I mentioned all commands:

```
<ext:commandextensions>
  <ext:commands>
    <ext:command name="Save" extendingcommand="AdditionalProcess" />
    <ext:command name="SaveClose" extendingcommand="AdditionalProcess" />
    <ext:command name="Localize" extendingcommand="AdditionalProcess" />
    <ext:command name="UnLocalize" extendingcommand="AdditionalProcess" />
  </ext:commands>
  <ext:dependencies>
    <cfg:dependency>CommandsExtensions.Commandset</cfg:dependency>
  </ext:dependencies>
</ext:commandextensions>
```

Once additional process done, I need to execute the command which has been extended.
For example:

```
return $cme.getCommand("Save")._execute(selection, pipeline);
```

### Question: How can I set parameter "Save" or "Localize" or "UnLocalize" based on the triggered event?

Or Simply, how Can I find in JS the Command which has been triggered
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

What I ended up doing a long time ago when I had the same need was to have a different extension for each command, then:

1. Set a variable with the name of the command the user called (`this.properties.CommandCalled="Save"`) or something along those lines
2. Call a "central" function which had the logic I wanted to execute
3. In that "central" function, have some logic to alter the behavior based on the value of CommandCalled